# Arrow not able to draw in exact 90 deg using div tag in html

Tags: html, svg

I am drawing an arrow using div tag in html. It is working fine. But the issue is, when I am trying to draw it in exact 90 deg, it is disappearing. Can someone help me find the issue?

```html
<div class="object-added arrowline" style="top:${shapeValues.top}px; left:${shapeValues.left}px">

  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
        <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000000;" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <defs>
      <marker id="markerArrowEnd" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
        <path d="M10, 2 L10,11 L2,6 L10, 2" style="fill: #000000;" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Please share you code by adding it to your question. Then it will be much easier to help.

Comment: I made your code visible. Please format it so it is easily readable.

Comment: Who do you set the rotation (that does not do the expected)?